# Генерировать Label из таблицы

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

При получении из таблицы записи, получаю только одну запись в `Lable` как сделать чтобы генерировались другие `Lable` по записи в таблице?

код ниже

```
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConString.ToString());
            string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM mon ORDER BY `Name_PC` + 0";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdString, con);
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.Text = reader["Name_PC"].ToString();
                label.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                this.Controls.Add(label);
            }
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток, дело в том что при таком выполнении программы в label будут отображаться только последние данные прочитанные из таблицы, что бы отобразить все данные, создайте либо datatable, либо массив из label, либо создайте переменную массива и помещайте все в массив, а после выводите в label те данные которые вам нужны. Удачи

Еще datagridview подойдет для вашей задачи. А если нет, пробуйте тогда заполнять массив своими данными а после выводить нужные значения в свой label.

Comment: datagridview не подходит

Answer (score 1):

В общем оказалось всё гораздо проще

```
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConString.ToString());
            string cmdString = "SELECT * FROM mon ORDER BY `Name_PC` + 0";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdString, con);
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var i = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.Text = reader["Name_PC"].ToString();
                label.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                label.Location = new Point(20, 25 * (i++));
                label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                this.Controls.Add(label);
            }
            con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще проще использовать присваивание "+=" и в конце строки Text добавить Line Feed "\n"

```
label.Text += reader["Name_PC"].ToString() + "\n";
```